# Can't sign into Google account from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I can't sign into my Google account when I am trying to deploy my app to Google App Engine via Eclipse.

> Missing required parameter: client_id

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like the problem is java version. As I have so many java version in my machine, my existing one is jdk 1.5 according to development of one project.

last few days ago, I installed

> `jdk 1.7`

and `change path in enviroment variables setting`,and updated eclipse plug in to prepare for andriod development to test. And just click to sign in google acount from eclipse, it was working again.

When I set back to jdk 1.5, can't log in again.

Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the Application ID and Version ?

Details on how to do so [here](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_appid_version.html).

Comment: yes. I did set. The same thing happens.

Comment: @PTY I got this error when I did not set those, make sure the application id and version is valid

Answer (score 0):

this error might occur when you use eclipse INDIGO.
At the moment only eclipse HELIOS is supported.

EDIT:

I also had a lot of trouble signing in but finally got my eclipse running.

Turns out there is a [plugin for Indigo](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download), but it is not listed on all pages correctly. However, I got it working with Helios and Indigo.

- Make sure you follow the [installation guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse?hl=en) exactly
- Use a "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" or add the webtools plugins from the update site
- Install the Android Developer Tools (ADT) BEFORE adding the google plugin, and make sure you restart your eclipse before you continue.

Comment: Hi @dube I use Helios Service Release 1.